# Xquery Get Position()

Tags: sql-server, xquery-sql

This is a part of our xml file.

```
                <point distanceTotal="162" seqNo="189">
                <lineSection id="395" track="1" direction="1">
                <outInfos>
                    <comment commentTypeId="4" priority="1"oneLiner="BOT">
                        <layerVPK seasonValue="S0"/>
                        <vectors>
                            <vector dateFrom="2016-12-11"/>
                        </vectors>
                        <frenchText>1x3 MH</frenchText>
                    </comment>
                    <comment commentTypeId="4" priority="1" oneLiner="bot">
                        <layerVPK seasonValue="S0"/>
                        <frenchText>Réception voie occupée</frenchText>
                        <dutchText>Test</dutchText>
                    </comment>
                </outInfos>
            </point>
```

We are uploading this to a SqlServer column and with XQuery we are fetching the values.
But, I can't find a way to get the position() coded, and basically T-SQL ROW_NUMBER or dense rank can't be used as not always all data exists.
As example the dutchText only exists on the second comment and there is no field that identifies the 2 comments....

This is the SQL Code

```
SELECT  fi.file_uid,
        fi.file_date,
        T1.ref.value('@id',           'varchar(100)') AS gTV_id,
        T2.ref.value('@id',           'varchar(100)') AS gTrn_id,
        T4.ref.value('@seqNo',        'varchar(100)') AS gTrnTPp_seqNo,
        T7.ref.value('text()[1]',     'varchar(1000)') AS gTrnTPpOiCDT_Text,
        T6.ref.query('/globalTrainVariant/trains/globalTrainVariant/train/timetablePoints/point/outInfos/comment[position()]') AS Test
   FROM ods.filesin fi
        CROSS APPLY fi.file_xml.nodes('declare namespace cern="http://...";
                                       (/cern:trains/globalTrainVariant)') T1(ref)
        CROSS APPLY T1.ref.nodes('declare namespace cern="http://...";
                                  (train)') T2(ref)
        CROSS APPLY T2.ref.nodes('declare namespace cern="http://...";
                                 (timetablePoints)') T3(ref)
        CROSS APPLY T3.ref.nodes('declare namespace cern="http://...";
                                  (point)') T4(ref)
        CROSS APPLY T4.ref.nodes('declare namespace cern="http://...";
                                  (outInfos)') T5(ref)
        CROSS APPLY T5.ref.nodes('declare namespace cern="http://...";
                                  (comment)') T6(ref)
        CROSS APPLY T6.ref.nodes('declare namespace cern="http://...";
                                  (dutchText)') T7(ref)
  WHERE fi.file_type = 'trains'
```

The code gives no errors, but the Test field  is always blank.

Any suggestions ?

Comment: I don't think the position function works like that. Also that's obviously not gonna return the position correctly because you're trying to use the path from T6. What _might_ work for you is a subquery with row_number() and an outer apply instead of a cross apply for T7(ref) to get the correct row number, then exclude those where t7.ref is null

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you would look up the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/xquery/context-functions-position-xquery), you would see that, as of now, you can't return the result of the `position()` function directly:

> In SQL Server, **fn:position()** can only be used in the context of a
>   context-dependent predicate. Specifically, it can only be used inside
>   brackets ([ ]).

However, there is a neat trick you can employ to get it. Namely, you can compare the position of the element with a known sequence and then return the matched value from that sequence. An example below illustrates that.

```
declare @x xml = N'<point distanceTotal="162" seqNo="189">
  <outInfos>
    <comment commentTypeId="4" priority="1" oneLiner="BOT">
      <layerVPK seasonValue="S0" />
      <vectors>
        <vector dateFrom="2016-12-11" />
      </vectors>
      <frenchText>1x3 MH</frenchText>
    </comment>
    <comment commentTypeId="4" priority="1" oneLiner="bot">
      <layerVPK seasonValue="S0" />
      <frenchText>Réception voie occupée</frenchText>
      <dutchText>Test</dutchText>
    </comment>
  </outInfos>
</point>';

with cte as (
    select top (1000) row_number() over(order by ac.object_id) as [RN]
    from sys.all_columns ac
)
select t.c.query('.') as [OutInfos], sq.RN as [TextPosition], x.c.query('.') as [DutchComment]
from @x.nodes('/point/outInfos') t(c)
    cross join cte sq
    cross apply t.c.nodes('./comment[position() = sql:column("sq.RN")]/dutchText') x(c);
```

In it, the CTE produces an ordered set of integers (I usually keep a special table around, but you can always construct one as you go), and match condition is specified in the XQuery expression that defines the `x(c)` output.

Comment: For people searching for something similar, here is the final query ...

Comment: SELECT ...
T7.ref.value('text()[1]', 'varchar(1000)') AS gTrnTPpOiCDT_Text,
xRows1.RN AS gTrnTPpOiC_seqNo, xRows2.RN AS gTrnTPpOiCDT_seqNo
...
CROSS APPLY ods.RowNumbers_5 xRows1
CROSS APPLY T5.ref.nodes('dec...";(./comment[position() = sql:column("xRows1.RN")])') T6(ref)
CROSS APPLY ods.RowNumbers_1 xRows2
CROSS APPLY T6.ref.nodes('dec...";(./dutchText[position() = sql:column("xRows2.RN")])') T7(ref)
WHERE fi.file_type = 'trains'

Comment: Had to cut some parts die to the comment-length limit. But With the original query aside one will be able to compose.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with Roger that the position() fuction cannot be called directly and should be inside []. However, there is a solution which doesn't require any additional tables and supports any number of rows by using recursion:

```
    declare @Xml xml = N'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<root>
    <n>1</n>
    <n>10</n>
    <n>5</n>
    <n>3</n>
    <n>11</n>
</root>';

with cte as
(
    select t.c.value(N'n[1]', N'int') n, 1 RowNum
    from @Xml.nodes(N'root[1]') t(c)
    where t.c.exist(N'n[1]') = 1
    union all
    select t.c.value(N'n[position() = sql:column("cte.RowNum") + 1][1]', N'int') n, cte.RowNum + 1
    from @Xml.nodes(N'root[1]') t(c)
    cross join cte
    where t.c.exist(N'n[position() = sql:column("cte.RowNum") + 1]') = 1
)
select *
from cte;
```

Answer (score 2):

It might be simpler and better performing to use [Node Order Comparison Operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/xquery/comparison-expressions-xquery#node-comparison-operator) in order to count the preceding //comment nodes in the XML tree.

I didn't test on huge XML documents, but it's definitely less I/O intensive, and was less CPU intensive on my contrived tests.

```
declare @x xml = N'<point distanceTotal="162" seqNo="189">
  <outInfos>
    <comment commentTypeId="4" priority="1" oneLiner="BOT">
      <layerVPK seasonValue="S0" />
      <vectors>
        <vector dateFrom="2016-12-11" />
      </vectors>
      <frenchText>1x3 MH</frenchText>
    </comment>
    <comment commentTypeId="4" priority="1" oneLiner="bot">
      <layerVPK seasonValue="S0" />
      <frenchText>Réception voie occupée</frenchText>
      <dutchText>Test</dutchText>
    </comment>
  </outInfos>
</point>';

select
    [OutInfos] = t.c.query('../..'),
    [TextPosition] = t.c.value('let $dutchText := . return count(../../comment[. << $dutchText])', 'int'),
    [DutchComment] = t.c.query('.')
from @x.nodes('/point/outInfos/comment/dutchText') t(c)
```