# Bulk import xml file to SQL server

Tags: sql-server

**Issue:**
I have a single .xml file containing 13.5k of data sets and need to import it into SSMS. Unfortunatly, it contain a style I never met before; first a column declaration part, then the data part without any specific column names. With thus, I have issues to catch the needed fields. On top of that the .xml may even be corrupt (incorrect hierarchical structure).

**Xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Root>
    <DMSContent format="LOL"/>
    <Archive name="Adressdossier" id="52" osguid="43AAEC21AC6C40F1BEDB34D92512ED84"/>
    <ObjectType name="Dokument" internal_name="CitizenFileDocument" id="262216" osguid="F287C984EB9E48BEA280BA46C305567C" type="DOCUMENT" modul="MULTIDOC"/>

    <Rowset>
        <Columns>
            <Column name="Salutation" type="TEXT" ostype="X" size="50" otype="FOLDER"/>
            <Column name="Name" type="TEXT" ostype="X" size="200" otype="FOLDER"/>
            <Column name="FirstName" type="TEXT" ostype="X" size="100" otype="FOLDER"/>
            <Column name="StreetNo" type="TEXT" ostype="X" size="100" otype="FOLDER"/>
            <Column name="City" type="TEXT" ostype="X" size="150" otype="FOLDER"/>
            <Column name="ZIP" type="TEXT" ostype="X" size="50" otype="FOLDER"/>
            <Column name="Country" type="TEXT" ostype="X" size="50" otype="FOLDER"/>
            <Column name="Birthday" type="DATE" ostype="D" size="50" otype="FOLDER"/>
            <Column name="Filename" type="INTEGER" ostype="9" size="100" otype="FOLDER"/>
        </Columns>
    </Rowset>
    
    <Rows>
        <Row id="2538">
            <Value>Mrs</Value>
            <Value>Doe</Value>
            <Value>Jane</Value>
            <Value>Main Street 5</Value>        
            <Value>Ghost Town</Value>
            <Value>5315</Value>
            <Value>Switzerland</Value>      
            <Value>12.12.2017</Value>
            <Value>jp4_B025DF7DBAFC49879103ECB8AE59C3A2.docx</Value>
        </Row>
        
        <Row id="2579">
            <Value>Mr</Value>
            <Value>Ding</Value>
            <Value>Chavez</Value>
            <Value>Sun Boulevard 3a</Value>     
            <Value>Alien City</Value>
            <Value>4586</Value>
            <Value>Germany</Value>      
            <Value>01.01.1980</Value>
            <Value>jp4_DCA9345C93E84F1697668E6ACDC596C9.docx</Value>
        </Row>
        
        <Row id="2580">
            <Value>Mr</Value>
            <Value>Dale</Value>
            <Value>Dick</Value>
            <Value>Beach Avenue 13</Value>      
            <Value>Zombie Village</Value>
            <Value>9513</Value>
            <Value>Italy</Value>        
            <Value>09.11.1911</Value>
            <Value>jp4_5DDBF2A05BD0421A8C53B0CC4EB64232.doc</Value>
        </Row>
    </Rows>
</Root>
```

**The usually used MS-Sql code snippet, of course not working for this type of .xml-structure:**

```
set ansi_nulls on;
declare @xmlfile xml;

select @xmlfile = bulkcolumn
from  openrowset(bulk 'C:\Meta.xml', single_blob) x;

select 
       id           =      c.value('@id', 'int'),
       Salutation   =      c.value('(Column[@k="Salutation"]/@v)[1]', 'varchar(60)'),
       [Name]       =      c.value('(Column[@k="name"]/@v)[1]', 'varchar(100)'),
       Birthday     =      c.value('(Column[@k="Birthday"]/@v)[1]', 'date'),
       [Filename]   =      c.value('(Column[@k="Filename"]/@v)[1]', 'varchar(100)')

into #Meta --

from @xmlfile.nodes('/root/rows') as T(c);

set ansi_nulls off;
```

Thank you in advance for any help!

Comment: *"first a column declaration part, then the data part without any specific column names"* - Not the worst layout. Saves on the file size, and makes the code iterating through the data simpler.

Comment: How big is the XML file? Can you use SSIS for data import? Does a tool like [htmltity](https://www.html-tidy.org/) (in XML mode) fix the structural errors?

Comment: I totally agree but me myself would use instead of all those <values> directly the column name like <Salutation>, <City>, <Filename>. But that's not the case in this file.

Comment: Well it does make the code simpler when you have an imperative programming language anyway.

Comment: Thank you a lot for the hints for fixing the structural errors. I found as well a possibility with Notepad++ plugin "xml tools".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL Server doesn't support `fn::position()` or `preceding-sibling::` syntaxes. But [you can use a hack involving `<<`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48792281/14868997) to get the position of each node.

So we calculate the position of each `Column` node, then push those values into the `Value` lookups

```sql
SELECT
  id         = x2.Row.value('@id', 'int'),
  Salutation = x2.Row.value('(Value[sql:column("ColIndex.Salutation")]/text())[1]', 'varchar(60)'),
  [Name]     = x2.Row.value('(Value[sql:column("ColIndex.Name"      )]/text())[1]', 'varchar(100)'),
  Birthday   = x2.Row.value('(Value[sql:column("ColIndex.Birthday"  )]/text())[1]', 'date'),
  [Filename] = x2.Row.value('(Value[sql:column("ColIndex.Filename"  )]/text())[1]', 'varchar(100)')

FROM @xml.nodes('/Root/Rowset/Columns') x1(Col)
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT
       Salutation = x1.Col.value('let $c:= Column[@name="Salutation"][1] return count(Column[. << $c]) + 1', 'int'),
       [Name]     = x1.Col.value('let $c:= Column[@name="Name"]      [1] return count(Column[. << $c]) + 1', 'int'),
       Birthday   = x1.Col.value('let $c:= Column[@name="Birthday"]  [1] return count(Column[. << $c]) + 1', 'int'),
       [Filename] = x1.Col.value('let $c:= Column[@name="Filename"]  [1] return count(Column[. << $c]) + 1', 'int')
) ColIndex

CROSS APPLY @xml.nodes('/Root/Rows/Row') x2(Row);
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=840fae2a90b3ef6986b63cbcd9c8e09f)

Comment: Nice workaround!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep your current approach of importing the file, you can, with the following changes:

```
set ansi_nulls on;
declare @xmlfile xml;

select @xmlfile = bulkcolumn
from  openrowset(bulk 'C:\Meta.xml', single_blob) x;

select 
       id           =      c.value('@id', 'int'),
       Salutation   =      c.value('(Value[count(/Root/Rowset/Columns/Column[@name="Salutation"]/preceding-sibling::*) + 1]/text())[1]', 'varchar(60)'),
       [Name]       =      c.value('(Value[count(/Root/Rowset/Columns/Column[@name="Name"]/preceding-sibling::*) + 1]/text())[1]', 'varchar(100)'),
       Birthday     =      c.value('(Value[count(/Root/Rowset/Columns/Column[@name="Birthday"]/preceding-sibling::*) + 1]/text())[1]', 'date'),
       [Filename]   =      c.value('(Value[count(/Root/Rowset/Columns/Column[@name="Filename"]/preceding-sibling::*) + 1]/text())[1]', 'varchar(100)')

into #Meta --

from @xmlfile.nodes('/Root/Rows/Row') as T(c);

set ansi_nulls off;
```

This finds the right `<Value>` position by looking up the `<Column>` of the given name and figuring out how many columns precede it. Not pretty, but effective.

If this is a one-off and/or you're certain of the column order, you can of course access the values directly.

```
       Birthday     =      c.value('(Value[8]/text())[1]', 'varchar(60)'),
```

Comment: Unfortunatly, I get an error; 'XQuery [value()]: XQuery-Syntax "preceding-sibling" not supported'. I assume it's not related to the SSMS version (18.10) or a module.

Comment: @kaspar Well you can always switch to the more direct syntax like `(Value[8]/text())[1]` (or possibly `string(Value[8])`).

Comment: You could use `<<` syntax instead https://stackoverflow.com/a/48792281/14868997

Comment: @Tomalek; thus I realized to read out my data. So you helped to solve it. Thank you a lot! Will vote for the solution of Charlieface as it will work in a general matter for others.